# Using redirect sends me to /tag/?search=input instead of /tag/input (Django URL argument from form)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a page where there is a path /tag/name_of_tag and you can see all posts tagged with that tag.
Inside the page, you can also select another tag in a form and go to that tag.
The problem is that instead of going to /tag/searched_tag, it goes to /tag/?search=searched_tag
How can I change it doesn't leave the ?search= part?

urls.py:

```
url(r'tag/(?P<input_tag>\w+)$', views.tag_view, name='tag'),
```

views.py:

```
def tag_view(request, input_tag):
    form = TagSearchForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = TagSearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            input = form.cleaned_data['search']
            print(input)
            return redirect('fortykwords:tag_view', input)

    else:
        form = SearchForm()    

    latest_post_list = Post.objects.filter(tags=input_tag, status__exact="published")
    paginator = Paginator(latest_post_list, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    posts = paginator.get_page(page)
    context = {'latest_post_list': latest_post_list, 'page_tag': input_tag, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'fortykwords/tag.html', context)
```

forms.py:

```
class TagSearchForm(forms.Form):
    search = tagulous.forms.SingleTagField(
    tag_options=tagulous.models.TagOptions(
        autocomplete_view='fortykwords:post_tags_autocomplete'
    ),
    label='Tags',
    required=True,
    help_text=_('Filter by lead tags.  You can organize leads by any tag you want.'),
)
```

tag.html:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form action="." method="get">
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<h3>Posts with the tag {{ page_tag }}</h3>

{% if latest_post_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for post in latest_post_list %}
            <li> {{ post.author }} {{ post.pub_date }} 
                    <br>  
            <a href="{% url 'fortykwords:detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
            {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
                <a href="{% url 'fortykwords:tag' tag.name %}">{{ tag.name }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No posts are available.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What's the output for `print(input)` ?

Comment: This code is not redirecting at all. The form is being directly submitted to the tag view, and since the form action is GET the form data is being sent as a querystring in the URL.

Comment: That's something strange that I noticed. It doesn't seem to print. If I go to tag/hello, search "animals" and submit, this is the terminal output:
`[06/Aug/2018 17:55:44] "GET /tag/hello HTTP/1.1" 200 3508
[06/Aug/2018 17:56:02] "GET /post-tag-autocomplete/?q=&p=1&_=1533578145634 HTTP/1.1" 200 151
Not Found: /tag/
[06/Aug/2018 17:56:05] "GET /tag/?search=animals HTTP/1.1" 404 4816`

Comment: @DanielRoseman You are right. What should I change?

Comment: Well this structure is all a bit odd. The 404 is because you don't have a pattern for just /tag/ with a querystring. I'm not really sure what you want to do.

Comment: Well what I want to do is that by default, if you go to tag/this, you get all posts with the tag "this". When you're in this list, there is a search bar where you can select a tag. Imagine that the user chose the tag "hello". Then, he submits and is redirected to website.com/tag/hello I don't want the querystring in the link at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the argument `input` to `redirect` method as `input_tag=input`.

**Example**:

```
return redirect('fortykwords:tag_view', input_tag=input)
```

Comment: It didn't change the behaviour.

Comment: Oh. I didn't see the name of the `url`. Your `url` has name `tag` while in `redirect`, you have used `tag_view`. See, if changing the name to `tag` helps.

Comment: I changed it to `return redirect('fortykwords:tag', input_tag=input)` and it still does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's showing as `/tag/?search=searched_tag` because your form is submitting by `GET` but never getting to the redirect. It seems `is_valid()` is returning `False`.

I've tested a very similar version of your code and don't think it's a bug in tagulous, but would still be interested to know what had gone wrong (I wrote tagulous). Spotted a couple of places you can streamline your code a bit, so try::

```
def tag_view(request, input_tag):
    # Can't see any POSTs in your example, so you can pass the form GET here
    # Might also be nice to pass the original tag in so it shows in the form
    form = TagSearchForm(request.GET, initial={'search': input_tag})

    # The form already has the GET, so you can go straight into the is_valid
    if form.is_valid():
        input = form.cleaned_data['search']
        print('Valid: ', input)
        return redirect('fortykwords:tag_view', input)

    else:
        print('Invalid: ', form.errors, form.non_field_errors)
    # You can remove the else for if not GET, which would never be reached

    # on to pagination as before
```

(although fwiw I'd recommend [ipdb](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ipdb+python) instead of `print`)

Comment: I did just that and it does the same thing. It never prints "Valid: ..."

Comment: You added the `else` to print the invalid message, with the form errors?

Comment: Indeed. Whenever I search something, it gives me `Invalid:  <ul class="errorlist"><li>search<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul> <bound method BaseForm.non_field_errors of <TagSearchForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(search)>>`